# How to use Promise.all correctly?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Consider the following code:

```
var result1;
var result1Promise = getSomeValueAsync().then(x => result1 = x);

var result2;
var result2Promise = getSomeValueAsync().then(x => result2 = x);

await Promise.all([result1Promise, result2Promise]);

// Are result1 and result2 guaranteed to have been set at this point?

console.log(result1 + result2); // Will this always work? Or could result1 and/or result2 be undefined because then() has not been executed yet?
```

When I use the then() method, is it guaranteed to have been executed in-order? E.g. then() will not execute immediately after Promise.all has been resolved?

It seems to work ok in Chrome, but what I'm really looking for is a guarantee that it will always work accroding to some spec?

I'd rather not use Promise.all(...).then(some callback) because then I'm back to using callbacks again...

Comment: Yes, that'll work, `.then` is just a substitute for `await`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes :) But I think you missed the point of the question, namely the order of which the then() callbacks are executed. For example, if the then() callback on line 1 executes after Promise.all's then, it will not work.

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer to assign values to external variables rather than using the return value of the `Promise.all` call?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant ah! that's what I should do. I wasn't aware that Promise.all returned the values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can directly use the return value of [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const p1 = getSomeValueAsync();
const p2 = getSomeValueAsync();

const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);

console.log(result1 + result2);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `Promise.all` will only resolve once all promises in its array have resolved. Because your two Promises have `.then`s of:

```
.then(x => result1 = x);
.then(x => result2 = x);
```

The `Promise.all` will resolve once both of these functions have completed. So yes, both `result1` and `result2` are guaranteed to be defined (or, at least, to have been assigned to) when the `Promise.all` callback runs.

Still, rather than assigning to outer variables, it might make more sense to define the variables with `const` *while* `await`ing the `Promise.all`:

```
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([getSomeValueAsync(), getSomeValueAsync()]);
```

Comment: But even if the promises in the array have been resolved, that doesn't guarantee that the then()'s of those promises have been executed?

Comment: Yes, it does - the Promise the expression resolves to will only resolve once all chained `.then` callbacks complete. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565326/how-promises-and-promise-chaining-works-problem-with-code/55565421#55565421 maybe, it might make things a bit clearer. Every time you call `.then`, you create a new Promise

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are set. Resolving result1Promise and result2Promise includes setting the result1 and result2 because the promise itself is only fully resolved when .then() is executed.

But if you wand to avoid callbacks at all you should structure your code like this:

```js
const result1Promise = getSomeValueAsync();
const result2Promise = getSomeValueAsync();

const results = await Promise.all([result1Promise, result2Promise]);

console.log(results[0] + results[1]);
```